# How can I summarize two rows into a new one in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

newbie here, I have this dataframe in r:

```
DF<- data.frame(
2014 = c(30,20,4), 
2015 = c(25,40,6), 
row.names = c("mobile login", "computer login","errors"))
```

as it shows:

```
              2014  2015
mobile login   30    25
computer login 20    40
errors         4     6
```

I want to add a new row, in which I have the total of logins, something like:

```
             2014  2015
mobile login   30    25
computer login 20    40
errors         4     6
total login    50    65
```

As far as I know, I can operate with columns, accesing them with '$'. Is there a way to do something like

```
DF$total <- DF$mobile + DF$computer
```

but with rows?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If errors is your last row, then `colSums(DF[-nrow(DF),])` should do it

Comment: `DF[1, ] + DF[2, ]`. Note the comma in the square brackets. In general, `[row, column]` enables you to define a specific cell if a single value is provided for both or a range of cells. With one of the values missing, you select the entire first  and second row.

Comment: @Sotos No, it is not. Columns goes from 2012 to 2015 and I have 10 columns, two of them has to be added and two of them subtracted, ending with 8. I pasted that as a little but representative example

Comment: `rbind(DF,"Total"=colSums(DF[which(rownames(DF)!="errors"),]))`

Comment: @TheoSloot, It is not clear what you mean. Could you provide a more representative example? Use `dput` as your current one also throws an error

Comment: @Sotos I already have the answer: Using the name of the row in brackets, as @ nya reply.

Final answer: `DF["total",] <- DF["mobile login",]+DF["computer login",] ` 

So it doesn't matter how many rows are in the data frame, because the rows are accessed by their names

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way,

```
DF <- rbind(DF, colSums(DF[rownames(DF) != 'errors',]))
rownames(DF)[nrow(DF)] <- 'total login'
#               X2014 X2015
#mobile login      30    25
#computer login    20    40
#errors             4     6
#total login       50    65
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to tidy up the data so it is easier to use aggregate functions. For example, if we transform your example data from wide to long as below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# tidy up
df_clean <- 
  DF %>% 
  add_rownames("Item") %>% 
  mutate(Type = ifelse(grepl("login", Item), "Login", "Other")) %>% 
  gather(Year, Count, -c(1, 4))

df_clean
#             Item  Type  Year Count
#            (chr) (chr) (chr) (dbl)
# 1   mobile login Login  2014    30
# 2 computer login Login  2014    20
# 3         errors Other  2014     4
# 4   mobile login Login  2015    25
# 5 computer login Login  2015    40
# 6         errors Other  2015     6
```

Then it is more convenient to summarise:

```
# summary example
df_clean %>% 
  filter(Type == "Login") %>% 
  group_by(Type, Year) %>% 
  summarise(TotalLogin = sum(Count))

#    Type  Year TotalLogin
#   (chr) (chr)      (dbl)
# 1 Login  2014         50
# 2 Login  2015         65
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there is, take a look at the `[`-function.
Like `df[ row, column]`.

Can I say that it would be better to include it as a real variable, instead of just as a row name? That makes it easier to have "tidy data" as described in [this paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf)